# How do I disable all the keys of the keyboard except for three?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

So I want to disable all the keys on my keyboard except for 'ctrl', 'alt', and 'E'. How do I do this with the help of a command that I can bind to a keyboard shortcut.
I figured out how to disable the entire keyboard using the following command ***xinput float 17***.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [xmodmap](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xmodmap.1.html):

> xmodmap - utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in X

1. Use `xmodmap -pke` to find out which keys have which keycode on your keyboard.
2. Disable a key by using `xmodmap -e 'keycode 24 = 0x0000'` replacing `24` with the respective keycode of the key which you want to disable.
3. Repeat step 2 for all listed keycodes to disable all keys. You can for example use a for loop to do so quickly:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
for i in {8..255}
do
    echo "Disabling keycode $i ..."
    xmodmap -e "keycode $i = 0x0000"
done
```

Comment: I just tried your command(in point 2), but it  doesn't seem to disable the keys. Why is that?

Comment: Have you replaced the key code ("24" in the example above) with the corresponding key code listed in `xmodmap -pke`?

Comment: yes i replaced it with the correct keycode

Comment: oh nvm it works now. But how do I enable it again

Comment: Like this for example: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 24 = q'`; Again, make sure that you're replacing "24" and "q" with the correct keycode / key.